# How I can make some elements of a column equal to each other?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column in my data set called “activity” with the following entries:

```
 (04)WORKING AT HOME (for pay)
 (03)AT HOME ACTIVITIES
 (02)WORK
 (01)WORK RELATED
 (07) Pick-up or drop-off passenger (non-work/non-school)
 (05) Drop off/Pick-up someone at their work
 (08) Drop off/Pick-up someone at their school
 (09)CHANGE MODE OF TRAVEL
 (10)TRANSFER BETWEEN
```

I want to change it to numerical data with following code:

```
as.numeric(df$activity)
```

I want

```
(07) Pick-up or drop-off passenger (non-work/non-school) 
(05) Drop off/Pick-up someone at their work
(08) Drop off/Pick-up someone at their school
```

to get same number.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a few factors, it can be done with `ifelse` (or `dplyr::if_else`) or similar constructs. I've even done "lookup dictionaries" of sorts, something like

```r
somedict <- c("some1"=1L, "any2"=4L, "all9"=4L)
somedict[ c("any2", "all9", "all9", "all9", "some1", "some1") ]
#  any2  all9  all9  all9 some1 some1 
#     4     4     4     4     1     1
```

But I think since you have so many, a better construct would be another frame and to `merge` (or `dplyr::left_join`) it in.

```r
possibles <- c(
 "WORKING AT HOME (for pay)",
 "AT HOME ACTIVITIES",
 "WORK",
 "WORK RELATED",
 "DROP OFF/PICK-UP SOMEONE AT THEIR WORK",
 "DROP OFF/PICK-UP SOMEONE AT THEIR SCHOOL",
 "PICK-UP OR DROP-OFF PASSENGER (NON-WORK/ NON-SCHOOL)",
 "CHANGE MODE OF TRAVEL",
 "TRANSFER BETWEE")

nums <- data.frame(topic = possibles, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
nums$num <- seq_len(nrow(nums))
nums$num[grepl("DROP", nums$topic)] <- min(nums$num[ grepl("DROP", nums$topic) ])
nums
#                                                  topic num
# 1                            WORKING AT HOME (for pay)   1
# 2                                   AT HOME ACTIVITIES   2
# 3                                                 WORK   3
# 4                                         WORK RELATED   4
# 5               DROP OFF/PICK-UP SOMEONE AT THEIR WORK   5
# 6             DROP OFF/PICK-UP SOMEONE AT THEIR SCHOOL   5
# 7 PICK-UP OR DROP-OFF PASSENGER (NON-WORK/ NON-SCHOOL)   5
# 8                                CHANGE MODE OF TRAVEL   8
# 9                                      TRANSFER BETWEE   9


set.seed(2)
dat <- data.frame(topic = sample(possibles, size=1000, replace=TRUE),
                  id = 1:1000,
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(dat)
#                                                  topic id
# 1                                   AT HOME ACTIVITIES  1
# 2 PICK-UP OR DROP-OFF PASSENGER (NON-WORK/ NON-SCHOOL)  2
# 3             DROP OFF/PICK-UP SOMEONE AT THEIR SCHOOL  3
# 4                                   AT HOME ACTIVITIES  4
# 5                                      TRANSFER BETWEE  5
# 6                                      TRANSFER BETWEE  6

newdat <- merge(dat, nums, by.x="topic", by.y="topic", all.x=TRUE, sort=FALSE)
newdat <- newdat[ order(newdat$id), ]
head(newdat)
#                                                    topic id num
# 1                                     AT HOME ACTIVITIES  1   2
# 175 PICK-UP OR DROP-OFF PASSENGER (NON-WORK/ NON-SCHOOL)  2   5
# 272             DROP OFF/PICK-UP SOMEONE AT THEIR SCHOOL  3   5
# 4                                     AT HOME ACTIVITIES  4   2
# 397                                      TRANSFER BETWEE  5   9
# 335                                      TRANSFER BETWEE  6   9
```

This method relies heavily on knowing all factors up-front, which might be seen as a weakness. One strength of it, though, is that you (should) immediately see when there is a new (or mis-spelled) topic, since you'll have an `NA` in that `num` column.

Comment: How I can apply your method to my data set? where I have 5000 rows?

Comment: See my edit, both for better definition of `nums`, and for a larger sample dataset. This works equally well for 5M rows as 50.

Comment: you changed your answer completely! did you see my edit?